# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderators

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed editing) the answer.
- The top voted nominations can go forward to become Moderators Pro Tem.
- Once the site leaves beta we can either reopen nominations or re-use the nominations on this thread.
- The voting will be done on a separate question, and not straight away.

Some guidelines:

1. Must be a currently registered user in good standing
2. Must have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
3. Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
4. Should lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
5. They should want the responsibility. Nominating users isn’t the same as an obligation. It’s purely voluntary!

Answer (score 1):

[Sruly](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/35/sruly) : Highest reputation at time of posting and a phenomenal number of answers.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the good word! :)